# Overlay an Image on Screen in Unreal

Tags: unreal

I need to overlay an image on the screen, the whole screen.
The process would be like:
A screenshot is captured by the camera. It's blended with another image and the resultant image is displayed on the screen. However, this overlaid image should not be seen by the camera.
How would I go about doing this in the Unreal Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the image to display on a UI/HUD of some sort?

You can either use a widget blueprint, or extend the HUD blueprint, and add a draw material function that draws a dynamic material with a vector parameter on it.

You can then set the image by setting the vector parameter of your material to the Texture2D file your image is.